# STM32Cube IDE Same code ends up runing or in hardfault... Russian roulete

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I ran into a problem where my IDE is trolling me.

I have a simple project, where i trace back from mcu via ITM (SWO), and basically what happens is when i lauch STlink debugger, it connects to device flashes program and then IDE ignores all breakpoints. I stop it manually to discover that i went from Reset handler to Default handler, i aliased all handlers to it except hardfault.

So then weird shit started to happen. i checked my code... nothing criminal. at all.. checked memory, everything is where it suposed to be. checked memory for vector table... again stack pointer is first, then adress of reset handler (thumb mode). everything is fine. i launch debugger again and it runs like a charm.

So i deciced to restart the debugger again without changing anything in code, and i ended up in hardfault... then i lauch it again no hardfault but i am in a default handler. and it randomly faults, or runs.  i spent 2-3 hours checking every single bit and instruction to see what could go wrong. but looks like it randomly picks where to go - hardfault, run normaly or decided it wants a default handler.

According to this memory it should at least try to go to reset handler
[image]

0x20010000 Stack pointer -  address is legit, checked it.

0x080001D5 points to reset handler at 0x080001D4.

0x080001C9 Default handler address, and the next one is hardfault.

**Now even more** weird stuff... i switched debugger to OPENOCD and...

```
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x20000084 msp: 0x20010000
```

it clearly tries hard to boot from RAM no idea why or what is going on my reset handler clearly tells it to look for smth else. and then after couple of restarts of a debugger it runs normaly.

**UPDATE:**

i am now 100% sure it is IDE's funky behavior. i step through the whole program in stand alone openOCD client and it runs like a charm. no hardfaults or other unexpected jumps to handlers.

Comment: so i will just go back to vs code and openocd. spending whole day debuging a debugger is not what i am looking for :)

Comment: I'm also seeing "random fault" behaviour with STM32CubeIDE v1.4.2. What version were you using?